# Saving slope of each iteration from a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

Have data variables (tcons and tleave). Trying to modify the below loop to extract/save the slopes for each iteration and plot the slope values as a histogram. Not sure how to find/ save the slopes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
plot(tcons,tleave, xlab="Time spent with conspecific (seconds)", ylab = 
"Time taken to leave a refuge (seconds)", main="Time spent with 
conspecific vs Time taken to leave refuge")

for(i in 1:10000) {print
  (abline(lm(sample(tcons)~tleave), col="lightgrey"))
    print(i)}
```

Comment: Until you get your code debugged,  you might want to use `for(i in 1:10)` instead of `for(i in 1:10000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the wrong model formulation, here's how you can save all the coefficients into a list and then merge this list into a data.frame. Now each coefficient is a variable.

```
N <- 10000
out <- vector("list", N)

for(i in 1:N) {
  mdl <- lm(sample(tcons)~tleave)
  out[i] <- coef(mdl)
}

out <- do.call(rbind, out)

hist(out[, 2]) # you can then plot histogram from slope, for example
```

Answer (score 1):

```
model1 <- lm(sample(tcons)~tleave)
slope <- model1$coefficients[2]
```

Then loop through and save as needed